# Drawing Weighted Bipartite Graph using python

Tags: python, networkx, social-networking, bipartite

I am trying to make a weighted bipartite graph using a dataset. I have a dataset as below-

[image]

```
i=0
for a in attributes_n:
  B.add_weighted_edges_from(
    [(row['Country'], a, row[a]) for idx, row in df.iterrows() if row[a] > weight_l[i]],
    weight='weight')
```

But I am getting errors while checking

```
bipartite.sets(B)
```

AmbiguousSolution: Disconnected graph: Ambiguous solution for bipartite sets.

Here I want to establish connection between the countries and different attributes, a country should be connected to a node (attribute) if it has a value greater than a particular threshold (mentioned in the list weight_l).

I have mentioned whatever I tried in the above block.

Comment: Please provide all the code we need to reproduce the error (dataset included)

Answer (score 0):

Bipartitie sets are determined via graph colouring. This results in a unique solution for each component of your graph. However, if your graph consists of multiple components, then there are multiple ways in which sets for different components could be joined to produce the final output. The solution is hence ambiguous resulting in the `Ambiguous solution` error.

Since you already know your two set though (countries and attributes), I am struggling to see why you even need to compute the sets.